# theme_root returning a truncated URI

Tags: php, functions

I'm unable to access the theme editor via the control panel, receiving 'Sorry can't edit files with .. in the name....' and after trying to trace back the cause, I've found that the theme_root is being returned as /home/websitename.co./(the rest is correct).

I'm at a loss to determine where the theme_root is being read/set from and why it's truncating the .co.uk to just .co. This last issue is causing it to fail the allowed_files error testing as it's reading ./ and falling over.

Any assistance in plain enough english for a non php coder to understand would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I've generally seen server website paths named with dots replaced by underscores (eg: `/home/websitename_co_uk`). I know dots can muck with some functionality when present in system paths so you might want to change that.

Comment: Hi Dan, where would I change that?

Comment: That isn't a wordpress thing but rather a server filesystem thing. Whoever is administering your server needs to rename that directory and update settings accordingly.